# Going to a Shiur without paying tuition

Tags: halacha, gezel-stealing, yeshiva-school

There are certain colleges out there that have a Torah learning component to them. For example: Gemara morning Seder 10am - 1pm, then Shiur is 1-2:30, then college classes.

In a case where one isn't attending the college, is it permissible to attend shiur if the college doesn't mind non-students learning in Seder but prohibits them attending shiur?

The reason maybe it's allowed is זה נהנה זה לא חסר. Would that principle apply here? Is there other aspects that must be considered?

Recap: Is there any problem with going to a shiur without paying. Is an institution or yeshiva able to require people to pay in order to hear shiur?

Comment: are you familiar with YU? Are you looking for a school or an halachic discussion?

Comment: Halachic discussion. Yes YU is one of those schools that this applies to. Landers as well

Comment: What does college have to do with it? The same applies to any Yeshiva that you don't want to pay tuition for.

Comment: It's just details . Does it matter? Please explain your reasoning for down voting

Comment: Wouldn't this be at least trespassing?

Comment: זה נהנה וזה לא חסר is not  an heiter but  a lack of nezek.  If the college prohibited this you are not allowed someone can prohibit his property to someone else.  If you hear being outside as Hillel made it is permitted but Pay attention to snow.

Comment: In Gemara Hillel has  no money to go into the Bet Midrash and climb on the roof to hear the Shiur.  But Snow cover her.

Comment: @kouty I don't remember that gemara completely can you source it?

Comment: Yoma 35b: אמרו עליו על הלל הזקן שבכל יום ויום היה עושה ומשתכר בטרעפיק חציו היה נותן לשומר בית המדרש וחציו לפרנסתו ולפרנסת אנשי ביתו פעם אחת לא מצא להשתכר ולא הניחו שומר בית המדרש להכנס עלה ונתלה וישב על פי ארובה כדי שישמע דברי אלהים חיים מפי שמעיה ואבטליון אמרו אותו היום ערב שבת היה ותקופת טבת היתה וירד עליו שלג מן השמים כשעלה עמוד השחר אמר לו שמעיה לאבטליון אבטליון אחי בכל יום הבית מאיר והיום אפל שמא יום המעונן הוא הציצו עיניהן וראו דמות אדם בארובה עלו ומצאו עליו רום שלש אמות שלג פרקוהו והרחיצוהו וסיכוהו והושיבוהו כנגד המדורה אמרו ראוי זה לחלל עליו את השבת

Comment: @kouty The source you quoted is really great (I looked it up). If you wrote an answer using that source and others it would be a good answer to my question possibly. I don't remember where but there a gemara that speaks about rabbi gamliel who stopped people from coming and learning, and when they forced him to step down they opened the bais midresh to everyone and how that was better. See edited question for better understanding of what I'm looking for.

Comment: "Is there any problem with creating an institution or yeshiva that requires people to pay in order to hear shiur?" How else do you expect any institution to function? Someone needs to pay the bills. Is every Jewish institution supposed to run on charity alone?

Comment: @DoubleAA A institute that forces kids to attend college and won't let them pay for just the learning track is the question. They could still make money by kids who WANT to attend the college and could charge kids a lower price for those who want to attend the learning program alone without the college. Money would not be an issue. Torah should be available to everyone. For free wouldn't make sense because people must be paid but in order to force them into college does not. That's hindering propels ability to learn. Givin that a college does this, can one attend shiur anyway.

Comment: You seem to be confusing what you happen to think is right to do with what they legally are allowed to do.

Comment: @huddie96 Babylonian Talmud 28a 7th line story about Raban Gamliel giving permission for everybody to enter study-hall

Answer (score 5):

If the entrance is not free, it seems from the Gemara that you cannot enter. A similar case is cited in Gemara Yoma 35b.

Yoma 35b:

> אמרו עליו על הלל הזקן שבכל יום ויום היה עושה ומשתכר בטרעפיק חציו היה
>   נותן לשומר בית המדרש וחציו לפרנסתו ולפרנסת אנשי ביתו פעם אחת לא מצא
>   להשתכר ולא הניחו שומר בית המדרש להכנס עלה ונתלה וישב על פי ארובה כדי
>   שישמע דברי אלהים חיים מפי שמעיה ואבטליון אמרו אותו היום ערב שבת היה
>   ותקופת טבת היתה וירד עליו שלג מן השמים כשעלה עמוד השחר אמר לו שמעיה
>   לאבטליון אבטליון אחי בכל יום הבית מאיר והיום אפל שמא יום המעונן הוא
>   הציצו עיניהן וראו דמות אדם בארובה עלו ומצאו עליו רום שלש אמות שלג
>   פרקוהו והרחיצוהו וסיכוהו והושיבוהו כנגד המדורה אמרו ראוי זה לחלל עליו
>   את השבת
>
> It was reported about Hillel the Elder that every day he used to work
>   and earn one tropaik, half of which he would give to the guard at
>   the House of Learning, the other half being spent for his food and for
>   that of his family.
>
> One day he found nothing to earn and the guard at the House of
>   Learning would not permit him to enter.
>
> He climbed up and sat upon the window, to hear the words of the
>   living God from the mouth of Shemayah and Abtalion - They say, that
>   day was the eve of Sabbath in the winter solstice and snow fell down
>   upon him from heaven.
>
> When the dawn rose, Shemayah said to Abtalion: Brother Abtalion,
>   on every day this house is light and to-day it is dark, is it perhaps
>   a cloudy day.
>
> They looked up and saw the figure of a man in the window.
>
> They went up and found him covered by three cubits of snow.
>
> They removed him, bathed and anointed him and placed him opposite the
>   fire and they said: This man deserves that the Sabbath be profaned on
>   his behalf.

Conclusion, if the Shiur is audible outside the door, you can hear, but maybe that you cannot go into the bet midrash.

An other topic is if only morally accredited students can be admitted (Berachot 28a):

> For Rabban Gamaliel had issued a proclamation [saying].
>
> No disciple whose character does not correspond to his exterior may
>   enter the Beth ha-Midrash.
>
> On that day many stools were added.

Takeway (thanks to @DoubleAA) the Bet Midrash is entitled to set the conditions of admission to Shiur.

Comment: Didnt rabbi gamliel get removed and they added seats and it was seen as a good thing that more could learn? Also doesn't mean they have the athority to make any restrictions. Just certain ones maybe

Comment: @huddie96 yes but this is not linked to the paiement i think,  also RG was not  wrong but his oponents opinion wins